# ASP.Net DIV FLIP CSS in form not working.

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I have a CSS flip, that activates on a button click. the issue is when I place it in the   in asp.net the flip doesn't work. I dont know if the asp.net form auto refreshes any help would be appriciated.

```
*/The Css /*

    .flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
    .flip-container.hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

And it works in the below format

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="NewUser.test" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="\_Layout\_Flip.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="\_Layout\_Layout.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
</form>
        <div class="flip-container" id="FLIPDIV">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="front">
                    Front
                    <button onclick="Flip()">Flip Me!</button>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    Back
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
    function Flip() {
        var x = document.getElementById('FLIPDIV');
        x.classList.toggle('hover');
    }
</script>
```

As soon as I try it in an ASP.NET Form the flip does not work. I need the form for ASP:textboxes etc..

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="NewUser.test" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="\_Layout\_Flip.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="\_Layout\_Layout.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="flip-container" id="FLIPDIV">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="front">
                    Front
                    <button onclick="Flip()">Flip Me!</button>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    Back
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function Flip() {
        var x = document.getElementById('FLIPDIV');
        x.classList.toggle('hover');
    }
</script>
```

I am going to assume the form does some can of refresh on any button press etc.. but I am no expert any help would be amazing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is placed within a form and it has no type attribute defined.
In this case it is assumed as type="submit", so on every click it simply submits your form and Flip() function can't show any visual changes.

Change your button this way:

```
<button type="button" onclick="Flip()">Flip Me!</button>
```

It should work now.